# Encontrar cuantas veces se repite un valor en varios intervalos de tiempo

Tags: sql, postgresql

Necesito encontrar cuantos equipos han estado en primera división menos de 10 temporadas.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
SELECT equipolocal,
       temporada 
FROM partidos 
GROUP BY equipolocal, temporada
```

Con este código obtengo por ejemplo para el AD Almeria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora necesito escribir en el código que AD Almería solo estuvo 4 temporadas, no consigo realizar este conteo...

Comment: Hola Sergi, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te fue util y en caso de que haya resuelto tu problema marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 1):

```
select equipolocal, count(*) as total  
from partidos
group by equipolocal 
having count(*) < 10
```

En esta consulta se agrupa por el **campo equipolocal** y se usa la **cláusula having** para filtrar los equipos cuyo total es menor que **10**, y finalmente se seleccionan los campos deseados utilizando la **función de agregación count**, la cual te va a servir para contar la cantidad de veces que aparece un equipo.